# Query a week like this in previous years

Tags: sql, date, dayofweek

I have a memorial site for disappeared people during the last argentinian dictatorship.

So, I need to show people that have been abducted "this week", that is: in a week around the date of today in any previous year. It should match the week with a loose definition of week, just three days prior and post now will do.

As the date I can get with any of my known libraries give me a week definition that includes the year (and even the time if i'm not careful enough :) I have trouble even conceptualizing the query.

Is there some recipe for this kind of situations? how would you approach this problem?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL? MS Sql Server? Postgres? ...?

Comment: I thought intentional to left that undefined to reach the most compatible solution. But I'm actually using mysql (innoDB) over django's orm.

Comment: Eventually I'd be using postgres... So that's, arguably, prefered...

Comment: The problem with keeping it generic, in this case, is that each RDBMS has it's own built in functions for dealing with date parts and date math. In this scenario you will need to add and subtract day intervals from a date, and possible pick out the month part of the date as well.

Comment: @JNevill I just did a step in that direction... I'l update the question to ask for mysql then. Since that's my blocker.

Answer (score 1):

In oracle you could use to_char(date, 'iw') to get number of a week in year.  You could use that,  or if you want simple three days back and forward you could use

```
trunc(dateFromEventsDatabase) between to_date(to_char(dateFromEventsDatabase, 'yyyy') ||to_char(sysdate,' mmdd'), 'yyyymmdd') - 3 and to_date(to_char(dateFromEventsDatabase, 'yyyy') ||to_char(sysdate,' mmdd'), 'yyyymmdd') + 3
```

For MySQL it should look like this

```
Date(dateFromEventsDatabase ) between date_from_str(concat(date_format(now(),' %Y'), date_format(dateFromEventsDatabase, '%m%d')),' %Y%m%d')  - interval 3 day and date_from_str(concat(date_format(now(), '%Y'), date_format(dateFromEventsDatabase,' %m%d')), '%Y%m%d') + interval 3 day
```

Comment: I'm updating the question to ask for a MySQL solution. Please see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36045357/query-a-week-like-this-in-previous-years?noredirect=1#comment59740311_36045357). Upvoted you, anyway, because I like the approach.

Comment: I added mysql version